# Do reading a read-only file locks the file

Tags: vb.net, windows-server-2003

I have a log file in Production server which keeps on getting updated by a program(very frequently. say 5 to 10 times per second.).

This log file obviously read-only to Dev server, and chances the file size go up to ~4MB.

I have a program in Dev environment. That periodically reads the file content and looks for a specific lines/keywords.

```
************************
If File.Exists(targetFile) Then
            Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(targetFile,             FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fs)
                    Dim all As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
                    allLines = all.Split(Environment.NewLine)
                End Using
            End Using
End If
********************************
```

My problem is, it looks like that reading from dev server locking the file[not sure]. So the service is PRD not able to access the file and throwing errors.

Answer (score 4):

You are using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyhc0kft(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) of the `FileStream` constructor. The documentation says

> The constructor is given read/write access to the file, and it is
>   opened sharing Read access (that is, **requests to open the file for
>   writing by this or another process will fail** until the FileStream
>   object has been closed, but read attempts will succeed).

If you want to allow other processes to read and write to the file, you must open in `FileShare.ReadWrite` mode, using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Correct in that the forth param FileShare is the answer - but it appears that .Read or .ReadWrite would allow others to access the file.

Comment: @rheitzman The OP says that the production server cannot write to the log file while the stream is open. You therefore need to open with Write or ReadWrite (depending on whether the server also reads from its own log file).

Comment: I think the issue was the dev program was locking the file accidentally causing server errors. You maybe correct that both programs need to use the FileShare() property, but my guess is just changing the dev program will do the trick.